# Informing the user about a 301 redirect

Tags: php, url, redirect, http-referer

Consider the following scheme:

```
site A ------> site B (old URL)  --- 301 redirect ---> site C (new URL)
```

## Here's what happens

The user visits site A. Site A contains a link to site B (old URL). When the user clicks on a link to site B, he is redirected to site C (new URL). Site B issues the redirect to site C.

## The problem

When the user finally reaches site C, I'd like to notify him about the redirection.

## What I've tried

- I've tried looking for an `HTTP_REFERER` header when processing incoming requests in site C, but the referrer URL seems to point to site A. I was expecting it to refer to site B. Am I missing something related to 301 redirects and the implementation of this particular header? I am aware it is set by the browser and may behave unexpectedly, but why can't one expect it to refer to site B (the one which issued the redirect)?
- Appending a `?redirected=1` query string to the end of the new URL when issuing the redirect sounds like a solution, but it requires a) ensuring canonical URLs are in place to avoid duplicate content and b) messes up the new URL which I'd like to keep as clean as possible inside the address bar;

There is always an option of showing an intermediate redirection page with a predefined timeout until Javascript or meta refresh redirection performs the magic, but I'd like to avoid this approach and show the message in the new website instead to avoid confusing both users and web crawlers as I've read that in-browser redirects are not as reliable as the server-side ones.

What is the general approach to solving this problem?

**Update:** What about redirecting from site B to, say, `example.com/redirect.php?referrer_url=oldurl&redirect_to=newurl` ?

The `redirect.php` would then detect `oldurl` as the referrer URL, flash the redirect message to the session and issue a 301 redirect to `example.com/newurl`. Is this a good idea from a SEO perspective?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but possibly browsers don't overwrite the Referer header because a 301 is taken to mean that the new URL *replaces* the old one, so the browser acts as though URL B never existed, and makes it look like the link went straight from A to C.

Comment: @IMSop Is there any other way to inform site C about the redirection? Perhaps redirecting to example.com/abc/redirect which in turn redirects to example.com/abc? This way example.com (site C) would be able to know about the redirection, but this also introduces an extra redirect.

Comment: Be careful of altering the scope of your question too much, or making into too much of a discussion. This site works best if you stick to describing the problem in the Question, and sticking to a single query which is not too opinion-based. If you find a solution yourself you can post it as an answer, or if a new angle occurs to you it may make sense to post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution to the problem.

site B (old URL) is redirected to a particular script at site C, whose job is to handle incoming requests and perform redirects if necessary.

For example, if a user browses site A and clicks on a link to site B, he is then redirected to site C's `redirect.php` script, which accepts two GET parameters: `referrer_url` and `destination`. `referrer_url` is the old link to site B and `destination` is a relative path at site C.

The script then makes sure that `destination` is not an absolute URL (to avoid massive redirects to other sites), appends it to the base URL of site C and redirects the user to an appropriate page. `referrer_url` is not necessary, but it may be used to detect the domain of the old site B URL (in case there are multiple different domains).

Answer (score 1):

You could send your own http-header with the redirect for example:

```
header('RedirectedFrom: www.something.com/ifoo/bar.html');
```

and use this at target site to recognize redirects

```
$headers = headers_list();
foreach($headers as $header) {
    list($name,$value) = explode(':',$header);
    if($value == 'RedirectedFrom') {
        // what ever you want to do
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've also considered this option, but is this standard practice? I was hesitant to try this at first, but it seems like a pretty decent solution after all.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work how you expect - the request to "C" is issued by the browser, not the server, so you have no control over what headers it contains. You can send a header back from the server when issuing the 301 response, but this will simply be discarded when it is received by the browser, and not be visible anywhere on the next request.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @IMSoP You are right, this would only work if the browser would keep the header. Delete answer?

Comment: What about using cookies instead?

Comment: @maxhb Cookies might be worth a try - as long as URLs B and C are on the same domain, in order to share cookies.

Comment: @IMSop I've updated my question with my current approach. Basically, I have a "redirector" script at site C which accepts two GET parameters: referrer and destination URLs. Site B sends its own address as the referrer and a destination URL, allowing me to detect its origin in site C. The script at site C then makes a proper redirect to the destination URL under the same domain (site C), resulting in two redirects overall. Of course, the referrer URL can be spoofed, but it doesn't really matter, because all I need to do is redirect valid users to the right place at the new domain.